# From table view to core data/sqlite iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My question would be so simple, but as I am new to iPhone development, I need to know.

I have populated my table by JSON data in View1. Now my requirement is that when a user clicks and hold a cell then a dialogue box will be opened then from there user will have to choose to save the  cell data in database.
And in View2 the same saved data will be shown to user in the table.

Can we implement this in iPhone?

Please tell me if there is any tutorial/example of core data or sqlite (whichever would be the best) for beginners. Because I haven't find any tutorial for table to core data

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the above @HeikoG link to know the tutorial for core data..Core data is the best way to store and retrieve data from database...But you cannot bring a dialog box using long holding a cell.Its not a good interface..Better you select a cell and expand it and then you can have a button there to add a specific cell to core data database...

Comment: I find it a little difficult to understand, here I have found one which is http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/